# Block parameters with block only scopes

Tags: ruby

A book says that you can have a variable whose scope is limited to a block even if another variable with the same name exists elsewhere in the program. And you can do it using `;` before this block variable inside vertical pipes.

But I get the same result with and without block variable `x` below:

```
def block_local_variable
    x = "Original x!"
    3.times do |i;x|
        x = i
        puts "x in the block is now #{x}"
    end
    puts "x after the block ended is #{x}"
end
block_local_variable
```

and

```
def block_local_variable
    x = "Original x!"
    3.times do |x|
        puts "x in the block is now #{x}"
    end
    puts "x after the block ended is #{x}"
end
block_local_variable
```

As far as I can see, there's no difference.

```
x in the block is now 0
x in the block is now 1
x in the block is now 2
x after the block ended is Original x!
```

The original `x` is still protected from change.

Am I wrong? This particular code snippet can have the same result, but in a broader perspective stuff is really different, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way to explain what your book is trying to tell you.

1) A block can see all the variables in the surrounding scope--at the time the block was created.  Here is an example:

```
y = 'hello world' #<-+  <--- Everything outside the block is part of the surrounding scope
                  #  |
func = lambda do  #<-|---- Block created now!
  puts y   #---------+
end

func.call   #=>hello world
```

The following is not necessary to know for your question, but it's good to know in any case: A block cannot see the variables in the surrounding scope--at the time it is executed.  Here is an example of that:

```
y = 'hello world'# <-+
                 #   |
func = lambda do # <-|------Block created now!
  puts y  #----------+
end

def do_stuff(f)  #<--- The def keyword creates a new scope.
#----------------------+ <-- The scope surrounding the block.
  y = 10    #          |
  f.call  #=>puts y   <---Block executed now!
#----------------------+
end

do_stuff(func)  #=>hello world
```

2) Inside a block, you can change the variables in the surrounding scope:

```
y = 'hello world'# <-----+
                 #       |
func = lambda do #       | 
  y = 'goodbye'  #-------+
end

func.call
puts y   #=>goodbye
```

3) Now what if you want to use a variable named 'y' inside your block, but you don't want to change a variable outside the block that is already named 'y'? In other words, you don't want to have to search through all your code to see if there is already an existing variable named 'y' that you might inadvertently change, which could cause errors?

```
y = 'hello world'

func = lambda do |;y|   #New y variable created, which 'hides' the outer y.
  y = 'goodbye'     #Assignment to the 'local' (or block) y.
end  #Block y is destroyed--'unhiding' the outer y.

func.call
puts y  #=>hello world
```

Note that the variables listed after the semi-colon are not parameter variables--func takes 0 arguments.  The semi-colon just tells ruby to create the variables specified after the semi-colon.

If you apply those rules to your examples, you should realize that in order to test out how the semi-colon works, inside the block in both examples you have to assign to a variable that exists outside the block. Your second example doesn't do that. In addition, your second example specifies a block parameter variable x.  A block parameter variable ALWAYS hides an outer variable with the same name(well, not in ruby 1.8.7), so you immediately bungled the example by doing that: inside the block an assignment to x will be an assignment to the x parameter variable.

Just remember two things:

1. A block parameter variable hides an outer variable with the same name (except in Ruby 1.8.7-).
2. A 'semi-colon variable' hides an outer variable with the same name.